# UWP Treeview with Data selector generating an error in App.g.cs when I resize the window

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, runtime-error, uwp-xaml

Team,
this is something very strange and I do not understand how to debug it.
I have a tree view. Within the tree view I have 2 types:
Customer
Visit

ALL root elements are Customers
ALL child elements are Visits

I've done some selectors to show the correct icons for the level:
[image: level 1 loaded]

Now when I open the leafs IF the list does NOT exceed the end of the tree view it works:
[image: Open within window size]

But if I open a leaf that EXCEEDS the window side: [image: Child opening beyond window size]

I get this error:[image: Error in App.g.cs]

Sender: the App
Exception:
`{"Specified cast is not valid."}`

Message:

```
"System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'TitoDoc2020.Models.MTreeViewVisit' to type 'TitoDoc2020.Models.MTreeViewPaz'.\r\n   at TitoDoc2020.Views.TitoDocPage.TitoDocPage_obj107_Bindings.SetDataRoot(Object newDataRoot)\r\n   at TitoDoc2020.Views.TitoDocPage.TitoDocPage_obj107_Bindings.ProcessBindings(Object item, Int32 itemIndex, Int32 phase, Int32& nextPhase)"
```

BUT I'm NOT casting that! I really do not understand where it could happen.

[Complete project](https://msavazzi.visualstudio.com/UWP%20-%20TitoDoc2020) visible here.

Comment: It would help to see your xaml/code for the tree and the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description of the error message, the reason for this is on the type conversion of the binding and has nothing to do with whether it is out of the window.

Please check your binding data to see if you have incorrectly bound `MTreeViewVisit` to `MTreeViewPaz`.

---

**Update**

The initial speculation may be that the adjustment of the window caused the change in the visible area, which in turn caused some `TreeView` entry loading problems.

I noticed that in the project you will create a `TitoDocContext` whenever it comes to loading data, which is not recommended.

You should only create a `TitoDocContext`, and pass the reference where it is needed, not use the `using` statement to release the Context. Because the frequent creation of `DbContext` will bring huge resource overhead, this may also be related to your `TreeView` entry loading exception. In fact, I created a List with 1000 entries and after getting rid of SqlServer, it worked well.

---

**Update**

I reproduced your question. From the point of view of the actual problem, it should be due to the reuse of entries within the `TreeView`. In order to reduce the overhead of system resources, `TreeView` (including `ListView` and `GridView`) will reuse previously rendered templates. Because you used `ItemTemplateSelector`, the actual data type and the reused template are inconsistent, causing an error.

My suggestion is to create a `UserControl` to replace `ItemTemplateSelector`.

**1. Extract the Visits collection and create a base class**

```cs
public class MTreeViewBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MTreeViewVisit> Visits { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MTreeViewVisit>();
}

public class MTreeViewVisit : MTreeViewBase { }
public class MTreeViewPaz : MTreeViewBase { }
```

**2. Create a UserControl**

*TestControl.xaml*

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PAZTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewPaz">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <FontIcon
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="&#xE77B;" />
            <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="VisitTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewVisit">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <FontIcon
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                    Foreground="{x:Bind ImageColor}"
                    Glyph="{x:Bind ImageSrc}" />
            <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind VisitDescr}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent"/>
</Grid>
```

**3. Create dependent attributes for internal conversion**

*TestControl.xaml.cs*

```cs
public MTreeViewBase Data
{
    get { return (MTreeViewBase)GetValue(DataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MTreeViewBase), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        var instance = d as TestControl;
        if(e.NewValue is MTreeViewPaz)
        {
            instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.PAZTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.VisitTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

**4. Modify your TreeView and ItemTemplate**

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="BaseTemplate" x:DataType="model:MTreeViewBase">
    <winui:TreeViewItem
        IsExpanded="False"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">
        <controls1:TestControl Data="{Binding}"/>
    </winui:TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>

<winui:TreeView
    ...
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BaseTemplate}"
    ... />
```

This can ensure that the two types have the same entrance, and the conversion is done internally, which can effectively solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Richard, I've checked that multiple times and I've NOT found any issue. The issue is FOR SURE related to the "out of screen" because if I start the app full scree, open 2 leafs... it works perfectly. Close app, start app, resize to be as small as possible, open 1 or 2 leafs... CRASH!!!!

Comment: You can try to post your project on [github](https://github.com) and post a link. Of course, do not include personal privacy data

Comment: Sorry, because of permission settings, I can not download the project. Can you upload the compressed package of the project to OneDrive or Github?

Comment: Thank you Richard. I thought the using was allowing more parallelism in the queries as they are generated in different tasks under the await/async model. Is it correct or wrong? in any case I've now added it as a public static variable in the App.cs. Is it ok or you have other suggestions?

Comment: For a single `DbContext`, only one query can be performed at a time. But if you only read the data without writing, you can consider extracting the data from the database (such as calling `ToListAsync`) and loading it into memory. The next query is performed through the extracted **List<T>**, which is faster and supports Parallel query

Comment: Richard can you check the new version? I've changed the context to be global, I've added a cache (List) to use LINQ parallel queries and the issue is present again. It cannot be due to my code as it appeared to be ok only when all queries using all the same context (so no parallelism).

Comment: new code: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohVtHaw3aCiwYppLFUrK58b8J3w9Q?e=7YbWPx

Comment: There is something REALLY here you can see it well https://postimg.cc/hQX0BjqV check the selected line, under it is IMPOSSIBLE to have people, they are shown as people but when I click on the item https://postimg.cc/2bcxMWgz in reality is an image, you can see it from the right part as the info are not of a contact but of the image. I really do not understand how's possible

Comment: Even more weird. If I open the program, go always to the same contact and open exactly the same sub items two times out of three I get the issue but the third one it works. The app is exactly the same, no rebuild!

Comment: Due to lack of data (I don't have your database), I can't reproduce this problem for now, but I think I have some suggestions:
1. What I mean by creating only one DbContext is to create a TitoDocContext as a global reference when the application is initialized. But in methods like `MTreeViewPaz.LoadDataAsync`, you are still creating a new DbContext instead of referencing an existing DbContext.
2. The rendering problem you mentioned may be caused by ListView virtualization. You can try to add a ScrollViewer to contain the TreeView for testing to see if the problem will occur.

Comment: Thank you Richard, working to create a DB with anon data for you!

Comment: Richard here we go with the database backup: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohVtHaw3aCiwZMVd6HAqj3X5JjgNA?e=CUxYCc DB is full of random data so you can use it with no issues. Also please download the new code with no Using and the memory caching as you suggested. The issue is still there

Comment: @MassimoSavazzi Hello, I modified my answer and gave a solution

Comment: #Richard it works! thank you. Would you suggest I do the same with a second control for the Content Templates?

Comment: If it did not cause an exception, we may consider keeping it. But if a rendering error occurs, you can consider to deal with it in the same way.

Comment: Richard I cannot understand this:
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">
                <controls1:TreeViewControl Data="{Binding}"/>
can you explain me why there is a {Binding} with no field? and not an {x:Bind}

Comment: Here, {Binding} is a special syntax, which means to bind the current DataContext, direct use of {x: Bind} has a similar effect, both can be used.