# UWP Changing from TemplateSelector to user Control does not show binding anymore

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, user-controls

Following the working solution provided from Richard Zhang - MSFT in my question [UWP Treeview with Data selector generating an error in App.g.cs when I resize the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993707/uwp-treeview-with-data-selector-generating-an-error-in-app-g-cs-when-i-resize-th/61003214?noredirect=1#comment108466986_61003214) I tried to convert the second group of data templates into a control to have a more clear code and try to address some other visualization issues.
The code compiles but it does not show anything.

Working code with TreeView Template Selector:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="ItemTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewBase"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <winui:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}">
                <controls1:TreeViewControl Data="{x:Bind}" />
            </winui:TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="PAZContentTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewPaz"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Cognome" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cognome}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Nome" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Nome}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Telefono 1" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Telef1}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Telefono 2" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Telef2}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Fax" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Fax}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Indirizzo" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Indir}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cap}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Citta}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="3"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cap}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text=")" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Nazione}" />

                </Grid>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Codice Fiscale" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.CodFis}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Nato il " />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind BornDate}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="in" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Naton}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Natoa}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Natop}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" />
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Clinica" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Clinica}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Presentato da" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.PresDa}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Assicurazione" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Assicurazione}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="APPContentTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewVisit"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock
                    Foreground="{x:Bind ImageColor}"
                    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="Analisi Patologia Prossima" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Clinica" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.Clinica)}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Data" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.DataS)}" />
                </Grid>

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Descrizione" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.Descr)}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

        <templateSelectors:TreeViewDataContentTemplateSelector
            x:Key="TreeViewDataContentTemplateSelector"
            APPTemplate="{StaticResource APPContentTemplate}"
            PAZTemplate="{StaticResource PAZContentTemplate}" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Padding="{StaticResource DetailPageMargin}" x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind SelectedItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewDataContentTemplateSelector}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

When I click an item in the TreeView the panel shows the correct info.

BUT if I try this:

TrewView.xaml

```
       <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Padding="{StaticResource DetailPageMargin}" >
            <controls1:TreeViewContentControl Data="{x:Bind (model:MTreeViewBase)SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"    />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

TreeViewContentControl.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TitoDoc2020.Views.TreeViewContentControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TitoDoc2020.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="using:TitoDoc2020.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            x:Name="PAZContentTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewPaz"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Cognome" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cognome}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Nome" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Nome}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Telefono 1" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Telef1}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Telefono 2" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Telef2}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Fax" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Fax}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Indirizzo" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Indir}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cap}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Citta}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="3"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Cap}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text=")" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Paz.Nazione}" />

                </Grid>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Codice Fiscale" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.CodFis}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Nato il " />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind BornDate}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="in" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Naton}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Natoa}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Natop}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" />
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Clinica" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Clinica}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Presentato da" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.PresDa}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Assicurazione" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Paz.Assicurazione}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate
            x:Name="APPContentTemplate"
            x:DataType="model:MTreeViewVisit"
            x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock
                    Foreground="{x:Bind ImageColor}"
                    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="Analisi Patologia Prossima" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Clinica" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.Clinica)}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftTopMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                        Text="Data" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftMargin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.DataS)}" />
                </Grid>

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="{StaticResource MediumTopMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}"
                    Text="Descrizione" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailBodyBaseMediumStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Visit.(model:TApp.Descr)}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TreeViewContentControl.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using TitoDoc2020.Models;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace TitoDoc2020.Views
{
    public sealed partial class TreeViewContentControl : UserControl
    {
#if LOG
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
#endif
        public MTreeViewBase Data
        {
            get { return (MTreeViewBase)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MTreeViewBase), typeof(TreeViewContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

        private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                var instance = d as TreeViewContentControl;
                if (e.NewValue is MTreeViewPaz)
                {
                    instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.PAZContentTemplate;
                }
                else
                {
                    //instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.VisitTemplate;
                    switch (((MTreeViewVisit)e.NewValue).Type)
                    {
                        // Generic Visits
                        case "APP":
                            instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.APPContentTemplate;
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (e.NewValue != null)
                            {
#if LOG
                                Logger.Error("Should never be default");
#endif
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        public TreeViewContentControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

It does not show any content in the x:Bind. The page is changed correctly, static text is shown but not the real data.

I think I've done exactly the same than the other control but cannot understand what I've messed up

Comment: Hello, if `MTreeViewBase` is a base class, and the data you pass in are derived from this class, you don’t have to add a conversion statement `(model: MTreeViewBase)` in the binding statement. Also check if your parent class which contain the `SelectItem` variable implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Hi Richard, The parent class is the TreeView page:
`public sealed partial class TitoDocPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private MTreeViewBase _selectedItem;

        public MTreeViewBase SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { Set(ref _selectedItem, value); }
        }`

Comment: and
`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`
So I would say I'm fine with the class. Even with the changes you suggested I have no update

Comment: Also Richard note that when I click on an item the page on the right changes accordingly (from PAZ to IMG to PLP etc...) but the data is not shown. So the         `private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)` is called every time with the correct item BUT the `x:Bind` in the data template does not work. For example: `<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />` but I do not have any error and if in VS2019 I right click on Name and choose **go to definition** menu it resolves correctly and opens the right item.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Peter Spada](https://github.com/spadapet) and his amazing help I was able to have it working:

here’s the problem: I'm setting instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate to a DataTemplate with `x:DataType=”model:MTreeViewPaz”`. However, `instance.MainContent` never has its `Content` or `DataContext` set, so it is using the default `DataContext`. The default `DataContext` is inherited from the XAML tree and comes from the root `ShellPage`:

That’s why the `InvalidCastException` failed to cast `ShellPage` to `MTreeViewPaz`.

I was able to fix it by manually setting the DataContext as seen below.

TreeViewContentControl.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using TitoDoc2020.Models;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace TitoDoc2020.Views
{
    public sealed partial class TreeViewContentControl : UserControl
    {
#if LOG
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
#endif
        public MTreeViewBase Data
        {
            get { return (MTreeViewBase)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MTreeViewBase), typeof(TreeViewContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

        private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                var instance = d as TreeViewContentControl;
                if (e.NewValue is MTreeViewPaz)
                {
                    instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.PAZContentTemplate;
                }
                else
                {
                    //instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.VisitTemplate;
                    switch (((MTreeViewVisit)e.NewValue).Type)
                    {
                        // Generic Visits
                        case "APP":
                            instance.MainContent.ContentTemplate = instance.APPContentTemplate;
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (e.NewValue != null)
                            {
#if LOG
                                Logger.Error("Should never be default");
#endif
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                instance.MainContent.DataContext = e.NewValue;

            }
        }
        public TreeViewContentControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```